# How to update records only storing changes?

Tags: python, json, sqlite, flask

My backend using Python and Flask splits [JSON data](https://data.vatsim.net/v3/vatsim-data.json) into various endpoints, to retrieve in my client Swift app rather than having to download the full data client-side.

JSON file :

```
{
  "pilots": [
    {
      "cid": 1234567,
      "name": "John Smith",
      "callsign": "TIA1",
      "server": "USA-WEST",
      "pilot_rating": 3,
      "latitude": 18.42663,
      "longitude": 116.15007,
      "altitude": 41038,
      "groundspeed": 435,
      "transponder": "2200",
      "heading": 154,
      "qnh_i_hg": 29.96,
      "qnh_mb": 1015,
      "flight_plan": {
        "flight_rules": "I",
        "aircraft": "B737/M-VGDW/C",
        "aircraft_faa": "B737/L",
        "aircraft_short": "B737",
        "departure": "LTBA",
        "arrival": "WAMM",
        "alternate": "",
        "cruise_tas": "437",
        "altitude": "33000",
        "deptime": "1230",
        "enroute_time": "1415",
        "fuel_time": "1542",
        "remarks": "PBN/B1D1O1S1 DOF/221107 REG/VPCTY EET/LTAA0020 UDDD0137 UBBA0151 UTAK0222 UTAA0247 UTAV0309 UTSD0322 UTTR0345 UAII0352 UTTR0354 UCFO0412 UCFM0434 ZWUQ0451 ZLHW0606 ZPKM0741 ZGZU0856 VHHK0946 RPHI1020 WAAF1251 SEL/EJKS CODE/ADF5D2 OPR/TEXAS AIR LLC ORGN/KCHIUALE PER/C  RMK/CALLSIGN \"TEXAS\"  /V/",
        "route": "ASMAP UL333 SIV UA4 ERZ UB374 INDUR N449 DUKAN A480 KRS B701 TUGTA A909 BABUM A477 POGON L143 TISIB L141 KAMUD W186 SADAN Y1 OMBON B330 AVPAM A599 POU B330 CH A583 ZAM A461 BONDA",
        "revision_id": 4,
        "assigned_transponder": "0363"
      },
      "logon_time": "2022-11-06T07:07:42.1130925Z",
      "last_updated": "2022-11-07T22:36:19.1087668Z"
    }
}
```

I import JSON into various SQLite tables. JSON data is updated every 60 seconds, so I need to update my copy accordingly. My current solution is to delete data in database then reinsert, but that's most likely not the right way. I'm not sure how I should go about diffing records in database against latest JSON, I could retrieve all records then compare old and new line by line, but this could be even less efficient. What's a robust way of doing this in Python?

Code to insert pilots and associated flight plans :

```
def _store_pilots(pilots):
    """Removes all records from the db, then stores pilots and associated flight plans, checking for duplicate CIDs."""
    pilots_list = []
    cid_list = []
    fp_list = []
    for pilot in pilots:
        cid = int(pilot['cid'])
        if cid in cid_list:
            continue
        cid_list.append(cid)
        pilot_tuple = (
            pilot['cid'], pilot['name'],
            pilot['callsign'], pilot['server'],
            pilot['pilot_rating'],
            pilot['latitude'], pilot['longitude'],
            pilot['altitude'], pilot['groundspeed'],
            pilot['transponder'], pilot['heading'],
            pilot['qnh_i_hg'], pilot['qnh_mb'],
            pilot['logon_time'], pilot['last_updated']
        )
        pilots_list.append(pilot_tuple)
        if pilot['flight_plan']:
            fp = pilot['flight_plan']
            fp_tuple = (
                pilot['cid'], fp['flight_rules'],
                fp['aircraft'], fp['aircraft_faa'], fp['aircraft_short'],
                fp['departure'], fp['arrival'], fp['alternate'],
                fp['cruise_tas'], fp['altitude'],
                fp['deptime'], fp['enroute_time'], fp['fuel_time'],
                fp['remarks'], fp['route'], fp['revision_id']
            )
            fp_list.append(fp_tuple)

    with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1")
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute("DELETE FROM pilots")
        c.executemany("""
            INSERT INTO pilots(cid, name, callsign, server, pilot_rating, latitude, longitude, altitude, groundspeed, transponder, heading, qnh_i_hg, qnh_mb, logon_time, last_updated)
            values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        """, pilots_list)

        c.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO flight_plans VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        )
        """, fp_list)
```

Comment: Is this the whole JSON object? What is the average size of your full payload? Few hundred bites?

Comment: This is just a small excerpt from the file, just downloaded a copy of it and it was 1 MB in size - this is also what I've typically been seeing while working with this data in terms of file size.

Comment: If you cannot monitor changes at the source, I don't see how attempting to make a diff can be any more efficient than the way you do it now, so long as you insert the data efficiently.

Comment: @PChemGuy Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately there's no way to know what's happening upstream when fetching the data. Definitely glad to hear I'm not completely off track with my approach to handling this task.

Comment: @Robin `cid` is unique key for each record(`pilot`, `controller`, ...)?

Comment: @Danila Ganchar That's correct, the CID is a unique identifier which should only appear once per pilot / controller.

Comment: @Robin you can create table with columns `pid`, `raw_json`, `json_hash` and update only necessary records. no? `update where pid = %(pid)s and json_hash != %(json_hash)s`.

Comment: @Danila Ganchar This sounds like a great approach actually, thanks! Just to clarify, when you say pid are you referring to the CID from the JSON pilot structure or some other identifier? Also, for calculating these hashes would you recommend hashlib MD5 or some other algorithm? My only concern would be that calculating all these hashes for each object in the JSON payload and then running the DB queries to find mismatches might be more resource intensive than just dropping and replacing all the data, however I just might give this a try and see what happens.

Comment: @Robin sorry. yes - `CID` ))) You can use build-in `hash()`. I didn't research hash algorithms performance. But I'm sure you can find many articles in network. Also you can add `record_type`(`pilot`, `controller`, ...) column if you have `CID` duplicates.

Comment: @Danila Ganchar Thanks for the clarifications, I'm still quite new to Python and was unaware of the built-in hash() function. I'll experiment with this approach but your comment was exactly the kind of advice I was looking for, do feel free to mark it as an answer and I'll accept .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table with columns `cid`, `raw_json_value`, `json_hash` and check `hash` value before `update` / `insert`. Here is an example:

```
data = [{'cid': 1, ...}, {'cid': 2, ...}, {'cid': 3, ...}]
for item in data:  # type: dict
    cid = item['cid']
    json_hash = hash(json.dumps(data))
    # Record - let's say a model from db
    record = get_record_by_cid(cid)
    if not record:
        save_record(cid, item, json_hash)
        continue
    
    if record.json_hash != json_hash:
        update_record(cid, item, json_hash)
```